# writing MIPS CODES using qtspim

Tags: mips, qtspim

I want to print type 123 in console of Qtspim.
and then print out "the answer = 123".

Why my mips code does not work??

```
# messages.asm 
 .data 
str: .asciiz "the answer = " 
 .text 


main: 

li $v0,5
syscall

li $v0, 4 # system call code for print_string 
la $a0, str # address of string to print
syscall # print the string 


li $v0, 1 # system call code for print_int 
syscall

li $v0, 10 # system call code for exit
 syscall # terminate program
```

Answer (score 1):

System call 1 (`print_integer`) expects the value to print in register `$a0`. In your program, `$a0` will not contain 123 when you perform the `print_integer` syscall, because you've set `$a0` to the address of `str`.

Comment: Place the value of `$a0` in another register temporarily while you print the string, and then restore it afterwards. When you program in assembly you always have to keep in mind what all the registers are used for at every location in your code.

Comment: Can I replace it with a1? la $a1, str

Comment: how to restore it afterwards??

Answer (score 0):

```
li $t0,123
li $v0, 1 # system call code for print_int 
move $a0,$t0
syscall
```

just make the following changes in the code and it will print "the answer = 123".
The problem arises because your a0 is still assigned to string but you need to assign it to the value of t0.
move $a0,$t0 will move the value of t0 to a0 and your code will work